# Append an element to a different element with the corresopnding index using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some images and their descriptions, currently loading in separate divs:

```
<div id="slideshow">

<div class="slide">IMAGE 1</div>

<div class="slide">IMAGE 2</div>

<div class="slide">IMAGE 3</div>

</div><!--end slideshow-->

<div id="captions">

<div class="slide"><div>CAPTION 1</div></div>

<div class="slide"><div>CAPTION 2</div></div>

<div class="slide"><div>CAPTION 3</div></div>

</div><!--end captions-->
```

I would like to move each caption to its corresponding image. It can be appended to either the image tag or its parent div.
Hoping for this:

```
<div id="slideshow">

<div class="slide">IMAGE 1</div>

<div>CAPTION 1<div>

<div class="slide">IMAGE 2</div>

<div>CAPTION 2<div>

<div class="slide">IMAGE 3</div>

<div>CAPTION 3<div>

</div><!--end slideshow-->
```

I tried something here, but it attached every caption to each image.

```
<script>
$('#captions .slide').each(function(){
        if ($(this).index().valueOf() == $('#slideshow .slide').index().valueOf()){
            $(this).detach().appendTo('#slideshow .slide');
            } else {
            $(this).hide();
            }

        });
</script>
```

I know this code is probably headed in the wrong direction. I'm happy to scrap it and start over.

Comment: Do you mean `<image>` or `<img>`? (I literally had to force myself to write `<image>`, it just seems so wrong.)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far (instead of just asking us how to do it).

Comment: Just bare in mind that `img` is a self-closing tag and doesn't allow any content within it.

Comment: But yes, that's a really simple task. Did you try something already?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the feedback so far. Thank you for your patience, this is my first attempt at using this forum. I fixed the formatting. I removed the confusing <image> tags (I know, it felt wrong to me too). I added my unsuccessful jQuery to the bottom. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is roughly what you're going for:

```
$('#captions .slide').each(function(i, v) {
    $('div', v).appendTo($('#slideshow .slide')[i]);
});
$('#captions').remove();
```